# How to access ecs task definition environment variables in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to access the environment variables set in a task definition, inside my nodejs app, with process.env.

I use a Dockerfile to create an image of the project, upload it to ECR, then use this image in the task definition.

I set enviroment variables for the nodejs app, inside the Dockerfile, like this:

```
# Dockerfile
...
RUN ROOT_DIR='/'
RUN PUBLIC_DIR='/public'
...
```

I have this task definition:

```
# task_definition.json
...
"environment" : [
    { "name" : "KeyOne", "value" : "KeyOneValue" },
    { "name" : "KeyTwo", "value" : "KeyTwoValue" }
]
...
```

I am not able to access `process.env.KeyOne` / `process.env.KeyTwo` (they are `undefined`)

I would like to be able to set those environment variables from the task definition and then reference them inside nodejs app with `process.env` instead of setting them inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: This should work, one note though, you dont set env vars with RUN command in docker

Comment: Apparently, setting them like this makes them available to `process.env`

Comment: hm, im not a node expert, but if thats the case, env vars are added to the process during the build, and not available at runtime

Comment: im rolling with similar setup, (laravel based project) and it works as expected

Comment: also do you have .env file in your project? Since it might silently fail if .env file is missing

Comment: I do have one. But I want to be able to use env vars set in task definition and it simply ignores them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a test I just made on my account, using ECS Fargate.  All env variables from the task definition are accessible from NodeJS code.

Source Code is at 
https://github.com/sebsto/ecs-demo/tree/master/so

TaskDefinition excerpt :

```
"environment": [
          {
            "name": "KEY1",
            "value": "VALUE1"
          }
        ],
```

Code extract :

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello world<br/>${JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2)}`);
});
```

Output :

```
Hello world
{ "KEY1": "VALUE1", "NODE_VERSION": "10.16.0", "HOSTNAME": "ip-10-0-0-83.eu-west-1.compute.internal", "YARN_VERSION": "1.16.0", "HOME": "/root", "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI": "/v2/credentials/b630982f-dffb-4ccc-9c8b-8311e42b57ab", "AWS_EXECUTION_ENV": "AWS_ECS_FARGATE", "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "eu-west-1", "ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI": "http://169.254.170.2/v3/12186f93-de7b-47e3-a096-b0f23d7e0e81", "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "AWS_REGION": "eu-west-1", "PWD": "/usr/src/app" }
```

I'll keep the container is up and running for a few months, you can test yourself at http://52.18.232.75:8080/